# read HTK binary file in matlab

Tags: matlab, header, endianness, htk

I run HTK package to extract MFCC features from my data. But now this features are stored in .mfc file format which is according to the htk book, big endian binary file. When I open these files in matlab there is some values which seems to be header values or something, any body knows how can I seperate header values from main data?

Comment: Check matlab file exchange http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange there are multiple submissions like this one http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32849-htk-mfcc-matlab/content/mfcc/readhtk_lite.m

Comment: Yep, I've seen it, but its' files don't exist anymore!

Comment: I don't understand. What is missing?

Comment: oh! Sorry, I checked mathwork, It seems they bound access for IPs from Iran! So i can not see codes which you are talking about!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code from [matlab file exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32849-htk-mfcc-matlab/content/mfcc/readhtk_lite.m) released unter [bsd lincense](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/view_license?file_info_id=32849)

```
function [ features, sampPeriod, parmKind ] = readhtk_lite( filename )
% READHTK_LITE Simple routine for reading HTK feature files.
%
%   [ FEATURES, SAMPPERIOD, PARMKIND ] = READHTK_LITE( FILENAME )
%   returns FEATURES from HTK [1] feature file specified by FILENAME,
%   along with sample period (s) in SAMPPERIOD and parameter kind
%   in PARAMKIND. Note that this function provides a trivial 
%   implementation with limited functionality. For fully featured 
%   support of HTK I/O refer for example to the VOICEBOX toolbox [2].
%   
%   Inputs
%           FILENAME is a filename as string of a HTK feature file
%
%   Outputs
%           FEATURES is a feature matrix with feature vectors 
%           as rows and feature dimensions as columns
%
%           SAMPPERIOD is a sample period (s)
%
%           PARMKIND is a code indicating a sample kind
%           (see Sec. 5.10.1 of [1], pp. 80-81)
%
%   Example
%           [ features, sampPeriod, parmKind ] = readhtk_lite( 'sp10_htk.mfc' );
%
%   References
%
%           [1] Young, S., Evermann, G., Gales, M., Hain, T., Kershaw, D., 
%               Liu, X., Moore, G., Odell, J., Ollason, D., Povey, D., 
%               Valtchev, V., Woodland, P., 2006. The HTK Book (for HTK 
%               Version 3.4.1). Engineering Department, Cambridge University.
%               (see also: http://htk.eng.cam.ac.uk)
%
%           [2] VOICEBOX: MATLAB toolbox for speech processing by Mike Brookes
%               url: http://www.ee.ic.ac.uk/hp/staff/dmb/voicebox/voicebox.html

%   Author: Kamil Wojcicki, September 2011


    mfcfile = fopen( filename, 'r', 'b' );

    nSamples = fread( mfcfile, 1, 'int32' );
    sampPeriod = fread( mfcfile, 1, 'int32' )*1E-7;
    sampSize = 0.25*fread( mfcfile, 1, 'int16' );
    parmKind = fread( mfcfile, 1, 'int16' );

    features = fread( mfcfile, [ sampSize, nSamples ], 'float' ).';

    fclose( mfcfile );


% EOF
```